# Неправильный classpath при запуске Tomcat в Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, tomcat

Происходит проблема при запуске *Tomcat* через *Idea*.

Если запускать тестовый класс, то все работает. Суть в том, что это не путь к файлу проекта, он "подменяется" путем к *Tomcat'у*.

Путь должен быть:

```
C:\Users\AntonioPrime\IdeaProjects\ProjectName\src\main\resources\ingredients.txt
```

Код:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("src/main/resources/ingredients.txt").toAbsolutePath()).filter(e -> !(e.equals(""))).forEach(e -> {
                Ingredient ingredient = constructIngredient(e);
                ingredients.put(ingredient.getName(), ingredient);
            });
```

Ошибка с по непонятным причинам другим путем:

> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4\bin\src\main\resources\ingredients.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что у вас относительный путь, поэтому, когда вы запускаете свой код из IDE он один, а когда он выполняется в контексте Томкэта, то другой.
Как я понимаю, этот файл - ресурс в вашем проекте.
Для того чтобы получить ресурс используйте что-нибудь вроде `this.getClass().getResource("/ingredients.txt")` или `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ingredients.txt")`
P.S. ваш вопрос не имеет ничего общего с classpath Tomcat :)

Comment: Ух ты, Спасибо! Я до этого натыкался на англоязычном StackOverflow на это решение, но подумал, что это какая то рефлексия, и точно ко мне не относится:)